# mysql.connector bug during "except" when compiled with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector, pyinstaller

I have a python program which makes mysql calls that I build into an exe using pyinstaller. 
The following problem occurs with either a --onefile or a --onedir compile using pyinstaller.

I have been able to use either mysqldb or mysql.connector to successfully connect and make queries.

Here is the mysqldb connect logic:

```
# from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=hostname,user=username,passwd=password)
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error",str(e.args[1]))            
    return
```

Here is the mysql.connector connect logic:

```
# http://dev.mysql.com/
try:
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host=hostname,user=username,password=password)
except mysql.connector.Error as e:   
    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error",str(e.msg))
    return
```

If I provide a bad host address then an "except" is thrown during both connect calls and the error message is trapped and displayed.  This works correctly for both connectors **before** I compile with pyinstaller.

However, the mysql.connector "except" **does not** occur in the compiled version of my program.  The "except" **does** work correctly for the mysqldb connect call and the error message appears.

This leads me to conclude that mysql.connector has a bug.  Can anyone else confirm this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: (removed previous comment) Can you put an 'catch-all' in the try/except to see what exception really happens?

Comment: I tried a generic except:, but nothing was caught in that case either

Comment: It simply does the try and the except never occurs.  Surprisingly, the code following the try/except never occurs either.  It appears stuck in the try.

Comment: connection_timeout = 2 .. Maybe it's suck resolving.

Comment: but it is not stuck when I use mysqldb and pyinstaller, and it is not stuck with mysql.connector or mysqldb when run as a script.  I am sure my code is fine.  There are only 2 possible causes.  1. pyinstaller cant handle mysql.connector properly OR 2. mysql.connector has a bug.  I have no idea which.

Comment: If I can't resolve this.. then I will have to use mysqldb instead of mysql.connector :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All these tools (pyinstaller,py2app,py2exe) do not support `try/except` the way you think.

The code generated has (well should have) both `try` and `except` clauses, but for the purposes of inferring which modules are actually needed by the program, only one branch is evaluated.

This may wreak all sorts of havoc with dynamic loading.

The simple, hackish fix is to include all the relevant imports directly, for example:

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector
import mysql.secret_lazy_loaded_submodule
import QtGui
import QtGui.QMessageBox
import QtGui.secret_lazy_loaded_submodule
try:
    mysql.connector.foo()
except Exception:
    QtGui.QMessageBox.foo()
```

Comment: How do you recommend I go about finding the necessary secret_lazy_loaded_submodule?

Comment: ok... I am using pkgutil.walk_packages to find all submodules... then I will try importing each until it works...

Comment: That was it!  In this case the secret_lazy_loaded_submodule that I had to import was mysql.connector.locales.eng.client_error.  Now the try/except is trapping the error successfully in the pyinstaller compiled version of my python program.  THANKS qarma !!!

Comment: Oh dear! Yes, Thanks! We, Connector/Python team, have to check this further. But now we know where to look.

Comment: Can you explain the sentence you mentioned: "All these tools (pyinstaller,py2app,py2exe) do not support try/except the way you think." What does this mean exactly?  I have a question related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70227633/try-except-works-in-pycharm-but-doesnt-work-in-exe-after-compiling-using-pyinst Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: @xie186 pyinstaller uses `ImportError`'s to determine which packages are actually needed in the phase where it gets rid of the bloat — it tries to run the application with 1 package less and checks if `ImportError` is raised — then that package is really needed. Thus code that has workarounds for failed imports typically ends up broken in the pyinstaller-bundled app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer for visibility, since part of my solution was tucked away in a comment.

I had the same problem, and the traceback for the error was something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "main.pyw", line 239, in start  
  File "database.py", line 89, in connected  
  File "database.py", line 57, in __enter__  
  File "site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 173, in connect  
  File "site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 102, in __init__  
  File "site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 731, in connect  
  File "site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 244, in _open_connection  
  File "site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 518, in open_connection  
  File "site-packages\mysql\connector\errors.py", line 187, in __init__  
  File "site-packages\mysql\connector\locales\__init__.py", line 60, in get_client_error  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client_error'
```

The import, like the comment said, is:

#### `import mysql.connector.locales.eng.client_error`