# How to use MySQLdb with unicode username, password, database?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to us MySQLdb to connect to my MySQL database.  Everything works as expected when I use a valid mysql user name like "fred", but fails when I try to use a valid mysql unicode user name, database, or password like "大な".

Who knows how to use MySQLdb with possible unicode characters?

Surprisingly, when I use mysql.connector instead of MySQLdb, I can connect with Japanese characters in my database, user, and password just fine (unable to test hostname with Japanese characters yet).  I would be happy to use mysql.connector, but I have another problem with that (see [mysql.connector bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657934/mysql-connector-bug-during-except-when-compiled-with-pyinstaller))

```
def fix(string):
    string = unicode(string)   # convert qstring from pyqt ui to unicode string
    string = string.encode('utf-8') 
    return string

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=fix(hostname), user=fix(username),  passwd=fix(password), port=int(port), charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)   
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    errno = e.args[0]
    err = e.args[1]

    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, "MySQL Connect Failed", err.decode("utf8")) 
    return
```

EDIT: I was able to resolve the [mysql connector bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657934/mysql-connector-bug-during-except-when-compiled-with-pyinstaller) so I will be using mysql.connector instead of MySQLdb, but this question is still valid.

Comment: As a side note - hostnames, by definition, cannot contain Unicode characters. They're restricted to ASCII alphanumeric characters and hyphens.

Comment: thanks duskwuff... at least I don't have to attempt to create that test case. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `charset` option in the `connect` method changes the character set *after* the connection is established. If you need Unicode for establishing the connection (e.g. because the username and/or password contains unicode codepoints) then one can use the `read_default_file` option.

Content of mycnf.cnf:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

and then in Python3 (better use an absolute path to the `mycnf.cnf` file):

```
#!/bin/python3

import MySQLdb

user="some name with unicode codepoints"
passwd="unicode password"
db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1", 
    user=user, passwd=passwd,
    charset="utf8mb4",
    read_default_file="./mycnf.cnf")

print("db:", db)

db.close()
```