# try/except works in pycharm but doesn't work in exe after compiling using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Test code:

```
## file name: test.py
import scanpy as sc
print(sc.__version__)
```

Then install `scanpy` using pip

```
pip install scanpy==1.8.2
pip install pyinstaller==4.7
```

I generated the exe file using the command line below:

```
python -m PyInstaller --noupx test.py
```

I then tried to run `test.exe`. I got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scanpy\_metadata.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "pathlib.py", line 1221, in read_text
  File "pathlib.py", line 1208, in open
  File "pathlib.py", line 1063, in _opener
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\xie186\\PycharmProjects\\pitaya\\test_exe\\dist\\test\\pyproject.toml'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "scanpy\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "scanpy\_metadata.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "scanpy\_compat.py", line 25, in pkg_metadata
  File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 984, in metadata
  File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 561, in from_name
importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for scanpy
[20028] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!
```

But when I run this script in pycharm, it works fine. I checked the code related to this error: https://github.com/theislab/scanpy/blob/16e62d1336a95966238113cdb5ab50f7d9f880ce/scanpy/_metadata.py#L24

In pycharm, the `try` part will fail and the code in `except` part will be executed. But in the `exe` file, it seems that the app will exit after the `try` part fails.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: "I got the error message:" you seem to have forgotten to include the error message you are getting.

Comment: My bad! Just added the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `--recursive-copy-metadata scanpy` solved my problem:

```
python -m PyInstaller --recursive-copy-metadata scanpy --noupx ..\test.py
```